# how better to cut laminate planks -- with saws or laminate cutter

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor, saw, circular-saw

In different videos I see that normally people prefer to use laminate planks cutter to table saw or similar. Is it just their preference or because of saw dust and such produced during sawing?

Comment: Not an expert, but not producing saw dust allows you to use the cutter in the same room that you are working on.

Comment: It depends on what the product is. "Laminate planks" refers to a huge array of materials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not use a laminate cutter.  For some laminates I am able to score with a razor knife and a straight edge and then snap, for others I use a miter saw for cross cuts, a table saw for ripping lengthwise and a jigsaw to cut around closet openings and door openings.

Answer (score 0):

A laminate cutter is faster, less messy, but there are scads of cheap ones that leave an ugly edge.  Buy or rent a good one.

If you a saw, splurge on a new blade for it.

If you use a table saw to cut it, because the material is so thin, you can use a Circular saw (skil-saw) 7.25" blade in it.  Get a carbide toothed one that is rated for cutting melamine. Laminate is basically MDf or HDF board.  This is tough on sawblades.

In either case, you will find you get a cleaner cut if put masking tape on the cutline.  Does not have to be good masking tape.